# Add dynamic row in a master-detail reactive angular 2 form

Tags: angular, forms, master-detail

I need to create a master-detail form that has the ability to dynamically add rows of detail. The problem arises in edit mode when I have to load the data. In practice, when I add formgroups through the formbuilder, I still do not know how many details ("Recapiti") will be returned to me from the Web API ... Is there a solution for this?

```js
.....
@Component({
  selector: 'formutenti',
  templateUrl: './formutenti.component.html',
  //styleUrls: ['./formutenti.component.css']
})
export class FormUtentiComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  complexForm: FormGroup;
  submitted: boolean;
  recapiti: Recapito[];
  myGroupName = ['Recapiti'];
 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.complexForm = this.fb.group({
      nome: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)])],
      cognome: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)])],
      myArray: this.fb.array([this.createItems(this.recapiti) //<==this.recapiti is undefined
      ])
    });

    if (this.data) {
      this.utentiService.getUtente(this.data)
        .subscribe(data => {
          (<FormControl>this.complexForm.controls['nome']).setValue(data['Nome'], { onlySelf: true });
          (<FormControl>this.complexForm.controls['cognome']).setValue(data['Cognome'], { onlySelf: true });
          this.recapiti = data['Recapiti'];
        });
    }
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private utentiService: UtentiService, private sharedService: SharedService, private notificationService: NotificationsService) {
  }

  createItems(recapiti: Recapito[]): FormGroup[] {
    let formGroups: FormGroup[];
    if (this.complexForm) {
      const control = <FormArray>this.complexForm.controls['myArray'];
      for (var _i = 0; _i < recapiti.length; _i++) {
        formGroups.push(this.fb.group({
          [recapiti[_i].IDrecapito]: this.fb.group({
            name: [recapiti[_i].IDrecapito],
            indirizzo: [''],
            telefono: [''],
            email: [''],
          })
        }))
      }
    }
    return formGroups;
  }
 
  initArray(nameObj: any) {
    return this.fb.group({
      [nameObj]: this.fb.group({
        name: [nameObj],
        indirizzo: [''],
        telefono: [''],
        email: [''],
      })
    })
  }
 
  addArray(newName: string) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.complexForm.controls['myArray'];
    this.myGroupName.push(newName);
    control.push(this.initArray(newName));
    (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('newName')).value = '';
  }
 
  removeDataKey(i: number) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.complexForm.controls['myArray'];
    control.removeAt(i);
    this.myGroupName.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I supouse you can any time make this.complexForm.get('myArray')=this.fb.array(this.createItems(this.recapiti))

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand. When i do this.fb.array([this.createItems(this.recapiti), this.recapiti is undefined because this.utentiService.getUtente(this.data) it is done later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a FormArray is the correct solution. You just have an issue with the order of execution in your application.

If you follow your code you can see that you initialize your FormGroup with your data *before* you get your data.

In my application, the code looks something like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productForm = this.fb.group({
        productName: ['', [Validators.required,
                           Validators.minLength(3),
                           Validators.maxLength(50)]],
        productCode: ['', Validators.required],
        starRating: ['', NumberValidators.range(1, 5)],
        tags: this.fb.array([]),
        description: ''
    });

    this.productService.getProduct(id)
        .subscribe(
            (product: IProduct) => this.onProductRetrieved(product),
            (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
}

onProductRetrieved(product: IProduct): void {
    this.product = product;

    // Update the data on the form
    this.productForm.patchValue({
        productName: this.product.productName,
        productCode: this.product.productCode,
        starRating: this.product.starRating,
        description: this.product.description
    });
    this.productForm.setControl('tags', this.fb.array(this.product.tags || []));
}
```

Notice that it is in the `onProductRetrieved` method, after the data has retrieved, that it populates the FormArray.

Hope this helps.